# PerformanceObserver throwing error in Firefox, working in Chrome

Tags: performance, pagespeed, observers, mutation-observers

I am implementing PerformanceObserver to track 'first-paint' & 'first-contentful-paint'.

```
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
  for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {

      if (entry.name === 'first-paint') {
        localStorage.setItem(rumMetrics.RUM_METRICS_FIRST_PAINT, entry.startTime);
      }
      else if (entry.name === 'first-contentful-paint') {
        localStorage.setItem(rumMetrics.RUM_METRICS_FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT, entry.startTime);
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log('local storage is not supported here. RUM metrics won\'t be recorded.');
    }
  }
});

observer.observe({ entryTypes: ['paint'] });
```

This works perfectly in Chrome **but throws an error in Firefox**.

```
TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type. (line: observer.observe({ entryTypes: ['paint'] });)
```

Comment: Sounds like something to report on https://bugzil.la

Answer (score 4):

**Update-1: 20th Apr 2018**

Mozilla has confirmed the bug and it is affecting FF61 Nightly as well

[image: Confirmed]

**Original Answer**

Confirmed that this is a bug even in the developer version.

[image: FF Deve]

[image: Bug]

Below is the bug for the same

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1454581